# expected unqualified error '{' before TEMPLATE1

Tags: c++, omnet++

morning guys, I'm running this code but I get the error: " expected '{' before TEMPLATE1",at the line of "brief Initialized a TEMPLATE1inate" even if I don't understand why it is required.

```
class MIXIM_API TEMPLATE1 : public cObject
    {
    public:
        /** @brief Constant with all values set to 0. */
        static const TEMPLATE1 ZERO;

public:
    BasicSafetyMessage BSM;

private:
  void copy(const TEMPLATE1& other) { BSM = other.BSM; }

public:
    /** @brief Default constructor. */
    TEMPLATE1()
        : BSM {}

    /** @brief Initializes a TEMPLATE1inate. */
    TEMPLATE1( BasicSafetyMessage bsm )
           : BSM(bsm) {}

    /** @brief Initializes TEMPLATE1inate from other TEMPLATE1inate. */
    TEMPLATE1(const TEMPLATE1& other)
        : cObject(other) { copy(other); }

    /** @brief Returns a string with the value of the TEMPLATE1inate. */
    std::string info() const;

};


inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TEMPLATE1& TEMPLATE1)
{
    return os << "(" << TEMPLATE1.BSM << ")";
}

inline std::string TEMPLATE1::info() const {
    std::stringstream os;
    os << *this;
    return os.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEMPLATE1()
    : BSM {}
```

I don't know what this is supposed to do. You are missing either a set of `()` or a set of `{}` or something else I cannot guess.

This is an empty default constructor, using the default constructor of BSM:

```
TEMPLATE1()
{
}
```

I think you want that.

Comment: You are right, I  silly missed a set of () of the BSM constructor. thanks a lot